# How to add Timestamp attribute to certification detail when signing pdf file

Tags: pdf, timestamp, digital-signature, signature

I want to display the Timestamp attribute in the certificate as shown in the picture

[image]

What should I set in the Signature?

This is my code for add sign info:

```java
private SignerInformation signTimeStamp(SignerInformation signer) throws IOException, TSPException {
    AttributeTable unsignedAttributes = signer.getUnsignedAttributes();

    ASN1EncodableVector vector = new ASN1EncodableVector();
    if (unsignedAttributes != null) {
        vector = unsignedAttributes.toASN1EncodableVector();
    }

    byte[] token = this.tsaClient.getTimeStampToken(signer.getSignature());

    ASN1ObjectIdentifier oid = PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signatureTimeStampToken;
    ASN1Encodable signatureTimeStamp = new Attribute(oid, new DERSet(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(token)));

    vector.add(signatureTimeStamp);
    Attributes signedAttributes = new Attributes(vector);
    // replace unsignedAttributes with the signed once
    return SignerInformation.replaceUnsignedAttributes(signer, new AttributeTable(signedAttributes));
}
```

Comment: Please share a pdf signed using your code.

Comment: @mkl
mkl. Yes. Please check it for me. Thank you.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12LZFn-sveKrcVvagk7QbhKf7a4Lxo-7Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @mkl Please check it help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: The TimeStamp attribute in the certificate simply provides you with the address of a timestamp server, it has no relation to the digital timestamp embedded in the digital signature. This is an optional attribute and it is added by the certificate issuer.

Comment: I just checked your example file, and it definitively does show the "The path validation and revocation checks were done as of the secure (timestamp) time." message on Adobe Reader. So all is well with your code. What you don't have is a "Timestamp entry" among the certificate attributes. But that's not the fault of the signing or timestamping code, that's an issue of the certificate issuing code.

Comment: @mkl
I also think so, because in the code it is not possible to set more properties in the certification information. Thank you.

Comment: @iPDFdev.  I also think so. Maybe this problem is from the timestamp certificate provider. Thank you.

Comment: @KJ *"using my second favourite says the doc was invalidated since it has apparently changed after signed"* - that *second favourite* incorrectly considers the document invalidated: The only change in the incremental update after signing is the addition of **DSS**, **Extensions**, and **Version** to the catalog. **DSS** for validation related information, **Extensions** and **Version** to document **DSS**. Any PDF validator supporting PAdES (either directly or by its inclusion in PDF 2.0), therefore, must not consider this update to invalidate the signature.

Comment: @KJ *"Interesting Older Acrobat reports Disallowed action type: URI  ..."* - Well, there is a single Link annotation to an external location. Forbidding this is very questionable. Which probably is why it's not forbidden anymore.

Comment: @DinhChu Did my answer sufficiently clear up the issue? Or are there still questions left?

Comment: Then you might want to mark the answer as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at its upper left, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png).

Comment: @mkl yes. I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To sum up the comments...*

Inspecting your example document it became clear that the timestamp you applied is alright. In particular you should get the lower message you marked in Certificate Viewer dialog screen shot:

[image: The path validation and revocation checks were done as of the secure (timestamp) time.]

On the other hand your code has no influence on whether or not you get the other entry you marked in that screen shot:

[image: Certificate data: TimeStamp - URI = http://aatl-timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/v4v5effk07zor410rew22z]

That entry is an extension of the signer X.509 certificate in which the issuer of that certificate provides the address of a time stamp service that may be used for timestamping signatures created by the private key associated with that certificate.

Thus, that entry *does **not** necessarily contain* the server used to create the actual timestamp, it's merely a proposition or recommendation.

So if the box in your screen shot that connects with the two markers claims some necessary relation between the marked TSA URL and reference to a secure timestamp time, it is wrong.