# How to show Creator in Detail of Signature in PdfBox

Tags: pdf, timestamp, digital-signature, signature

I want to display the Creator in Signature Detail. In "Signature was created using Not available."

[image]

This is my code for add sign info:

```
private void signDetached(SignatureInterface signature, PDDocument document, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    PDSignature pdSignature = new PDSignature();
    pdSignature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
    pdSignature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    pdSignature.setName("jvmfy");
    pdSignature.setReason("Learn how to sign pdf with jvmfy.com!");

    // the signing date, needed for valid signature
    pdSignature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    // register signature dictionary and sign interface
    document.addSignature(pdSignature, signature);

    // write incremental (only for signing purpose)
    // use saveIncremental to add signature, using plain save method may break up a document
    document.saveIncremental(output);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked in the [PDF 32000 specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) for `Prop_Build`. This isn't implemented in the PDFBox example, and after searching for "PDF Signature Build Dictionary Specification" I think it's confusing. But this attempt works, based on what I saw in an existing signed PDF:

```
COSDictionary pbDict = new COSDictionary();
COSDictionary appDict = new COSDictionary();
appDict.setName(COSName.NAME, "PDFBox");
pbDict.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("App"), appDict);
pdSignature.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Prop_Build"), pbDict);
```

Comment: Thank you. I added code and checked it ok.

Comment: Tilman Hausherr
I have other question. Please check it for me. Thank you so much.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69933844/how-to-add-timestamp-attribute-to-certification-detail-when-signing-pdf-file?noredirect=1#comment123630342_69933844

Comment: This one is for mkl 

Comment: I think you know this problem so it will be solved. Glad to have your help.

Comment: No I don't. I've never seen a certificate like this. Also mkl is really an expert in this topic.

Comment: Yes, I'm also waiting for his support.

Comment: *"I've never seen a certificate like this."* - Actually I also merely seldom see certificates with that extension, it's not usual in the CAs I mostly deal with.